# Unable to install telegram through Software (appstore) in xubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, software-center, gnome-software, telegram

This problem is with all the apps which I try to install, it shows (in the case of telegram) :- unable to install "Telegram Desktop":
snap "telegram-desktop" has "install-snap" change in progress.
Everytime when I try to install this shows up at the top of the Software.
PS I've installed telegram through terminal by `sudo apt install telegram`but please help me fix this issue with the software center.

Comment: How did you install telegram from terminal? What commands did you use?

Comment: Sudo apt install telegram

Comment: please edit your question and add the commands from terminal including the error

Comment: I want it the GUI way.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install telegram-desktop`

Comment: Few explanation would be welcome, even for such an as simple answer as this one

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked, unfortunately. It would be nice to learn how to install it ´through snap, independent of the distro, if this error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

need use:

```
snap changes
```

and find status Doing and kill this ID

```
snap abort <ID>
```

PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

Just wait a little bit
While the software is being downloaded and installed, hitting the install button again and again, pops up that message.